# Actionbarsherlock Spinner background image stretched

Tags: android, android-actionbar, styles

I am trying to change the color of the little triangle on the Actionbar spinner (sherlock).  I have done so using the following code:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_drawer</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyActionBarSpinnerStyle</item>

</style>

<style name="MyActionBarSpinnerStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_spinner_background</item>
</style>
```

The icon triangle is changed but it seems to stretch the image to the whole size of the spinner.

[image http://dodsonsolutions.com/screens/screen1.png](http://dodsonsolutions.com/screens/screen1.png)

I am using the patch-9 drawable file that everyone says to use:
[spinner http://dodsonsolutions.com/screens/spinner_background_disabled.png](http://dodsonsolutions.com/screens/spinner_background_disabled.png)

If this is not the correct dimensions of the file then does anyone know what it should be? 
Or how do I get it not to stretch and just sit in the bottom right hand corner.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**are you using the image that has correct extension?**

check the extension of the png file you are using. if it is not ".9.png", change it into .9.png

**or if it is .9.png?**

there must be a build error of your project. try to rebuild & run. that must be solved.

Comment: This Did it!  Thank you.  I was unaware that I needed to keep the .9 in the name.

Answer (score 0):

1.try to define pixel in the area that you want to re-size not all around the image and check pixel more than 3 mostly declaring 1 pixel not working 
2.check your xml file to make sure layout_width and layout_height is wrap_content 
3.To use 9patch :the image file extension should be png and while you declare area extension become .9.png